# How to replace all the characters with * using Regular Expression

Tags: python, html, regex, django, django-templates

I am having a text like

`s = bluesky`

I want to get it as `s = *******` (equal no of * as no of characters)

I am searching for a regular expression for Python.

Edit 1 :

```
b = '*'*len(s)
```

How can we do it in Django Template?

Comment: Manoj Govindan has already added the answer to do this in Django Template.

Comment: @pyfunc: He asked again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819260/is-there-any-filter-in-django-to-display-asterisk-instead-of-text) and I answered his other question too. No idea what he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we do it in Django Template

In a Django template? Dead easy.

```
{% for char in s %}*{% endfor %}
```

Where `s` is the template variable whose value is `bluesky`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
s = 'bluesky'
b = '*'*len(s)
print b
```

output :

```
>>> s = 'bluesky'
>>> b = '*'*len(s)
>>> print b
*******
```

Comment: unless that `s = ` bit is part of the string.

Comment: @Mark: Looks like it is not from the example that he has given. This is a typical newbie question that comes from some one with C/C++ background. Doing this in C/C++ would have been a small exercise. Simple question like this tells how python rocks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @Rajasekar can actually assign values, which is what your answer effectively tells him to do. I'm pretty sure that he is looking for `string.replace()` while thinking he needs `re.subn()` to do the job...

Comment: @Kimvais : I would have added that as solution in my reply too. And since you have already done that, I left my reply as is. All answers together form a response.

Answer (score 2):

No need for regexp, just `text.replace('bluesky','*'*len('bluesky'))`

e.g:

```
>>> text = "s = bluesky"
>>> text.replace('bluesky','*'*len('bluesky'))
's = *******'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)", lambda m: "%s = %s" % (m.group(1), '*'*len(m.group(2))), "s = bluesky")
's = *******'
>>> re.sub("(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)", lambda m: "%s = %s" % (m.group(1), '*'*len(m.group(2))), "cat=dog")
'cat = ***'
```

Assuming your string is literally `s = bluesky`