# Is there any filter in Django to display asterisks (*) instead of text

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am eager to know whether any filter is available for displaying all the text as * like this

```
mytext = 'raja'
```

`{{ mytext|password }}` should show `****`

How can we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Do this:

```
{% for char in mytext %}*{% endfor %}
```

That said, can I ask you where you are displaying the password? Usually passwords are not displayed on screen. If you want to display it in a form you can use a [`PasswordInput`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput) widget.

As @Ars said it is a bad idea to reveal the length of the password. You might want to display a random number of asterisks instead.

Comment: I guess that this involves password masking and is such a bad idea the way it has been asked. +1 for directing him to the widget.

Comment: Sir, May i Know why password masking is bad. I am only returning no of * to the browsers as (****)

Answer (score 2):

is this really a password?  Then it seems like a bad idea -- do you want to reveal that the password is 4 characters long?  Just print 4 (or 5 or whatever) asterisks straight in the template always.

Otherwise, I wouldn't bother with a filter.  Simply pass in a string of asterisks through the context:

```
mytext = 'raja'
ctx = Context({'mytext': '*' * len(mytext)})
t = Template('password: {{ mytext }}')
s = t.render(ctx)
```